# Why does a TensorRT engine need to "warmUp" to get accurate inference profiling?

Tags: tensorrt

The `trtexec --help` binary shows that `--warmUp=N  Run for N milliseconds to warmup before measuring performance (default = 200)`.

However, why is a warmup needed? If the model (and thus intermediate buffers necessary for the forward pass) are allocated during model load time, then the only performance bottleneck would be the Host to Device Memory transfers. The [nvidia docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/developer-guide/index.html#trtexec-benchmark) indicate that this is corrected for by their enqueing strategy.

Therefore I'm not sure what else could result in an initial performance bottleneck. Any insight on why this is needed would be much appreciated.

Comment: Warmup is needed generally in all benchmarking. That is why it is also needed in TensorRT. Are you confused why there is benchmarking in TensorRT or why the benchmark results get better after running the benchmark a few times? You can verify the effect by disabling the warmup and checking how that affects to your results.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am confused about why the benchmarking results get better after running the bechmark a few times. I have verified that warmup does affect the results but was curious why that would happen.

Comment: I think it has to do with memory and caches. There is initial overhead for "cold" caches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TensorRT needs warmup for multiple reasons:

- GPU could be in idle mode and the driver needs some time to go to an acceptable performance mode for profiling. You could use `nvidia-smi` to see the current mode.
- on some configuration, the driver is not in persistant mode and should be loaded when calling the first CUDA function
- in some cases, the driver needs to compile the PTX code found in the executable to get the BIN corresponding to the target architecture.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.89.02    Driver Version: 528.49       CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:65:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   47C    P8    36W / 350W |    473MiB / 12288MiB |     14%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```